# Error ITMS-90032 in xcode when submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, submit, info.plist

When I want to submit my app to the app store I keep getting this message :[image]

Does anyone know where I have to place this file or if I have to rename / delete it somewhere?

This is my info.plist file : [image]

And this is my directory : 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I changed minimum support to ios6 so there were unused images listed in my `info.plist`. I took them out and violá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Select the Target
2. Go to Build Phases
3. Expand the Copy Bundle Resources
4. Go to the bottom of the panel and select the <kbd>+</kbd> sign.
5. Add each of the missing resources.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't seem to find it. Could you give me a screenshot?

Comment: Some thing like that [image](http://shiki.me/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/offlinemap-xcode.jpg)

Comment: I just figured out that the "icon.png" in the .plist should have been "Icon.png". :) Thank you for your help!